# Reg exp: string NOT in pattern

Tags: regex

I have problems constructing a reg exp. I think I should use lookahead/behind but I just don't make it.

I want to make a **reg-exp that catches all HTML tags that do NOT contain a string** ('rabbit').

For example, the following tags should be matched

> <a XXX> <span yyy> </div x zz> </li qwerty=ab cd> <div hello=stackoverflow>

But not the following

> <a XXrabbitX> <span yyyrabbit> </div xrabbitzz> </li rabbit=abcd hippo=9876> <div hello=rabbit>

(My next step is to make make a substitution so that the word rabbit enters the tags, but that will hopefully come easy.)

(I use PHP5-preg_replace.)

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're matching the HTML tags with a regex something like this:

```
/<[^>]*>/
```

You can add a negative look-ahead assertion in there to assert that "rabbit" cannot be found in the tag:

```
/<(?![^>]*rabbit)[^>]*>/
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it doesn't work for me. After matching a string, also the tags that should NOT match are gone. I am sorry, I am trying to include the example, but I haven't mastered the editor in stack overflow.

$string = "<a XXX> <span yyy> </div x zz> </li qwerty=ab cd> <div hello=stackoverflow> <a XXrabbitX> <span yyyrabbit> </div xrabbitzz> </li rabbit=abcd hippo=9876> <div hello=rabbit>";
$pattern = "/<(?![^>]*rabbit)[^>]*>/";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "[MATCH]", $string);
<br>
Output
    [MATCH] [MATCH] [MATCH] [MATCH] [MATCH]

Comment: I copy-and-pasted your example and it works for me, on both php 5.2.6 and php 5.3.5.

Comment: So you get the following output?
`[MATCH] [MATCH] [MATCH] [MATCH] [MATCH] <a XXrabbitX> <span yyyrabbit> </div xrabbitzz> </li rabbit=abcd hippo=9876> <div hello=rabbit>`
I just get five [MATCH] and nothing more.
I use PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: I apologize, my error, it works for me now, thread solved. Thanks Anomie

Comment: Anomie's regex works perfectly here, too. Please post the code you are using to apply this regex.

Comment: Like I just wrote it is my mistake, I applied the example wrongly. (I thught I was looking at text output but it was HTML.) Anomie's reply is fine, thanks. Thread solved.